How can I change a single column to multiple columns in excel
I have a dataset in excel that is similar to this:

I am trying to transpose the Status field so each category is its own column like the following:

There should no longer be any duplicates for the ID#, each row should have a unique ID. I used a pivot table to get the ID#, and separate the status column into multiple columns but can’t add location or date.

Tips? Directions? Should I be doing this without a pivot table? The data in the images are made up, the actual dataset is much larger. Any help is appreciated.

As per the suggested duplicate, with a pivot table, add ID, Location, Date to "Rows". Then in the ribbon select "Design" and under "Report Layout" select "Show in Tabular Form". Under "Subtotals" and "Grand Totals" you can add / drop (sub)totals as required.

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

If you insist for an Excel Formulas then for simplicity and sake of readability you could try using the PIVOTBY()


=PIVOTBY(CHOOSECOLS(B3:E12,1,2,4),D3:D12,E3:E12,ROWS,,0,,0)


Or Using Power Query -- add the following in the advanced editor of a blank query, after converting the source ranges into structured references aka tables:


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Merged = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Merged", each Text.Combine({Text.From([ID], "en-US"), [Location], Text.From([Date], "en-US")}, ":"), type text),
    Pivot = Table.Pivot(Merged, List.Distinct(Merged[Status]), "Status", "Merged", List.Count),
    DataType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Pivot,{{"Date", type date}}),
    Reorder = Table.ReorderColumns(DataType,{"ID", "Location", "Cancelled", "Arrived", "Checked", "Rescheduled", "Date"})
in
    Reorder



If you have Excel 365 you will be better off using a formula to pivot your data.
If you prefer using Pivot Tables, just put your Location and Date fields in the Rows field:

